# Change this timer function to accept argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer

I have this working timer function in python ver3.6 which runs at an interval of 2 seconds.

```
def timer_function_working():
    threading.Timer(2, timer_function_working).start()
    print ("stackoverflow")

timer_function_working()
```

I want this timer_function to accept the time interval as an argument. Here is the new code;

```
def timer_function(interval_sec):
    threading.Timer(interval_sec, timer_function).start()
    print ("stackoverflow")

timer_function(interval_sec=2)
```

However, I get this error message;

```
TypeError: timer_function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'interval_sec'
```

How do I change this timer function to accept argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs for `threading.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Timer), the first argument to `Timer` is `interval`

> `class threading.Timer(interval, function, args=[], kwargs={})`

In your second code block, the first execution runs without issue because you've provided a value for `interval`. However, when the `function` is invoked at the end of the `Timer`'s duration, you don't pass any arguments to the function itself, which leads to the error:

```
TypeError: timer_function() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

You can pass an argument to the function that `Timer` invokes upon completion in the following way:

```
import threading


def timer_function(interval_sec):
    threading.Timer(interval_sec, timer_function, args=[interval_sec]).start()
    print ("stackoverflow")


timer_function(interval_sec=2)
```

Alternatively, you can use a closure to bind the value `interval_sec` to another function, defined within `timer_function` that can be called without any arguments:

```
def timer_function(interval_sec):
    def inner_function():
        return timer_function(interval_sec)
    threading.Timer(interval_sec, inner_function).start()
    print ("stackoverflow")


timer_function(interval_sec=2)
```